# Узнать размер файла в интернете средствами C++

Tags: c++, http

Очень непростая ситуация - у меня есть некий сервис, работающий на C++, и он должен раз в n часов (или дней) проверять размер zip-файла на одном конкретном сайте. Можно ли каким-то образом узнавать размер файла по ссылке, не скачивая его при этом каждый раз?

Comment: HEAD  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file

Comment: К сожалению, предложенный вами вариант подразумевает использование php, мне же необходимо использовать именно C/C++...

Comment: Тебе нужно распарсить HTTP заголовок и получить оттуда значение поля Content-Length

Comment: @Erlas HEAD-запрос можно слать из плюсов тоже.

Comment: Он не подразумевает использование PHP. Только HTTP. Как именно отправлять HTTP-запрос, [это уже на ваш выбор](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822581/2076787).

Comment: Пример показывает технику, а не подразумевает копирование как есть...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть curl. Его  библиотека написана на  С. 
`res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD, &file_size);`

Comment: Или, может кому то краше, [обертка](http://whoshuu.github.io/cpr/) на плюсах.

Comment: Благодарю - то, что нужно!